# apt-get upgrade fail

Tags: 16.04, apt, package-management, upgrade

I am stuck with this one, have tried `apt-get install -f`, `dpkg --configure -a` and they both tell me about the same.

I have no held packages (`dpkg -l|grep -i '^h'` is empty). Where do I start to look?

```
# apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 compiz-plugins : Depends: compiz-core (= 1:0.9.13.1+17.10.20170901-0ubuntu1) but 1:0.9.12.2+16.04.20160823-0ubuntu1 is installed
                  Depends: compiz-plugins-default (= 1:0.9.13.1+17.10.20170901-0ubuntu1) but 1:0.9.12.2+16.04.20160823-0ubuntu1 is installed
 libcompizconfig0 : Depends: compiz-core (= 1:0.9.13.1+17.10.20170901-0ubuntu1) but 1:0.9.12.2+16.04.20160823-0ubuntu1 is installed
 libgail-3-0 : Depends: libgtk-3-0 (= 3.22.25-0ubuntu0.1) but 3.18.9-1ubuntu3.3 is installed
 libmetacity1 : Depends: metacity-common (= 1:3.26.0-1) but 1:3.18.7-0ubuntu0.3 is installed
                Depends: libgtk-3-0 (>= 3.20.0) but 3.18.9-1ubuntu3.3 is installed
 metacity : Depends: metacity-common (= 1:3.26.0-1) but 1:3.18.7-0ubuntu0.3 is installed
            Depends: libgtk-3-0 (>= 3.21.5) but 3.18.9-1ubuntu3.3 is installed
 unity : Depends: libunity-core-6.0-9 (= 7.4.0+16.04.20160906-0ubuntu1) but 7.5.0+17.10.20171010-0ubuntu1 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

EDIT: As one answer comments, there are some mixed versions. This is because I tried to do a dist-upgrade to get rid of the error earlier. Apparently it has changed the error, but I believed it to be the same error, and didn't find the dist-upgrade relevant. My bad. I'll look into remove those pkgs then.

EDIT2: I don't think this is an exact duplicate of the two mentioned, at least not on at level I can comprehend.

QUESTION ANSWERED: I think the answers froms user535733 and karel are the ones that helped me. I'm sorry I do no seem to be able to accept the answer officially - could that be because the question is marked as a duplicate? I will try to accept again later.

Anyway: I pegged my installation at 16.04 (`apt-get install -t xenial`) and went around disabling the 17.10 packages. But then I got lost, gave up and made a clean 17.10 installation. Thanks for your time :-)

Comment: Have you run `apt-get update` recently? What Ubuntu version do you use?

Comment: The tag says 16.04, but the unmet dependencies results in the question say Depends: ...  17.10.

Comment: You seem to be trying to mix packages from two different releases of Ubuntu. That's unwise for several reasons...including that it breaks your system in precisely this way. Pick which release you want, and stick to it. Uninstall all packages from the other release, and remove those sources.